# Cannot convert null to object using Twipsy

Tags: javascript, asp.net, tooltip, twitter-bootstrap

I'am using a Twitter Bootstraper in my WebAplication, in my materpage i do the following

```
    <%--Referencing jQuery--%>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.js"></script>

<%--Referencing the bootstraper script--%>
<script src="http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/1.4.0/bootstrap-twipsy.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<%--My Script--%>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("a").twipsy();
    });        
</script>
```

then in page (Default.aspx) code ia have a single link like this:

```
<a href="#" id="example" class="classeTeste" title="Some title text">text</a>
```

When a run the page the twipsy (a stylized tooltip) doesnt work. 
Look here to see twipsy in action (http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#twipsy)

I see the "normal tooltip"

Inspecting the console of chrome i see the follong script error
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot convert null to object     (bootstrap-twipsy.js:315)

Whats wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your JQuery version is too old, that might be why.

Another possibility is that your selector is $("a") instead of an id, $("#mylink"). The docs suggest that it should work with a collection, though.

Comment: I tried to run my code with jQuery via CDN and not work and if i run the $("a") in the console window of chrome it finds the element.

Comment: thats right, i download the last version of jQuery an it works fine